# TypeError: path must be a string; CodeEval Prime Palindrome Error

Tags: javascript

I have the correct solution for getting the Prime Palindrome question on CodeEval, but keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: path must be a string
```

Here is my solution:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2])
  .toString()
  .split('\n')
  .forEach(isPrime)

function isPrime(input){
  if (input === '') return;

  if (input < 1001 ) {

    var output = '';

    for (var i = 2; i < input; i++) {

      if ( input % i === 0 ) {
        input--
      } else {
        output = input;
      }
    }
  }
  palindrome(output)
}

function palindrome(prime){
  var str = prime.toString();
  if (str.split('').reverse().join('') === str){
    console.log('str', str)
  } else {
     str--
    isPrime(str)
  }
}
```

Because CodeEval only accepts answers via console.logs, I have to console.log the outputs and it does show the correct solutions in my terminal.

Am I missing something or is this an error in CodeEval ?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike most CodeEval challenges, Prime Palindrome takes no input -- you should take out your fs.readFileSync etc., and just have your solution find and "Print to stdout the largest prime palindrome less than 1000."